# erlang connect with mongodb error with multithread

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I use localhost:27019,27020,27021 as mongodb server
when I first connect with it by 5 thread, each process read a data.it will throw exceptions. if I use 3 or less thread ,it will be ok.

but when I succeed in connect with it by 3 thread, if I use the same connection by 100 process,it won't throw exceptions any more unless I reconnect the mongoserver.

```
            =ERROR REPORT==== 3-Aug-2013::11:28:37 ===
            ** Generic server <0.164.0> terminating 
            ** Last message in was {modify,#Fun<mvar.2.15158540>}
            ** When Server state == {{dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
                                           {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                            []},
                                           {{[],[],[],
                                             [[{"192.168.17.100",27019}|{}]],
                                             [],
                                             [[{"192.168.17.100",27021}|{}]],
                                             [],[],[],[],[],[],
                                             [[{"192.168.17.100",27020}|{}]],
                                             [],[],[]}}},
                                     #Fun<mvar.1.22957847>}
            ** Reason for termination == 
            ** {badarg,[{dict,fetch,
                              [{"localhost",27021},
                               {dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
                                     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                                     {{[],[],[],
                                       [[{"192.168.17.100",27019}|{}]],
                                       [],
                                       [[{"192.168.17.100",27021}|{}]],
                                       [],[],[],[],[],[],
                                       [[{"192.168.17.100",27020}|{}]],
                                       [],[],[]}}}]},
                        {mongo_replset,remove_host,2},
                        {sets,fold_bucket,3},
                        {sets,fold_seg,4},
                        {sets,fold_segs,4},
                        {mongo_replset,'-fetch_member_info/1-fun-3-',3},
                        {mvar,'-modify_/2-fun-0-',2},
                        {mvar,handle_call,3}]}
            Pid {<0.88.0>,
                 {badarg,[{dict,fetch,
                                [{"localhost",27021},
                                 {dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
                                       {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
                                       {{[],[],[],
                                         [[{"192.168.17.100",27019}|{}]],
                                         [],
                                         [[{"192.168.17.100",27021}|{}]],
                                         [],[],[],[],[],[],
                                         [[{"192.168.17.100",27020}|{}]],
                                         [],[],[]}}}]},
                          {mongo_replset,remove_host,2},
                          {sets,fold_bucket,3},
                          {sets,fold_seg,4},
                          {sets,fold_segs,4},
                          {mongo_replset,'-fetch_member_info/1-fun-3-',3},
                          {mvar,'-modify_/2-fun-0-',2},
                          {mvar,handle_call,3}]}} Exit!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the error log that the connection are stored in the process dictionary as `{"192.168.17.100",27019}`...
and that the program fails when it looks for a a tuple of the form `{"localhost",27021}`. Obviously your localhost address must be `192.168.17.100`, and between the different tests you are making, you calls, directly or not, the `dict:fetch/2` function with different form of localhost ("localhost" and "192.168.17.100").